# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'timestamp' of undefined' when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an error which appear when I import jQuery lib only. I don't know what I can do. I know that it's coming from the file jquery.min.js.

Here is my simple page causing this error :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I get from my console :

[image: Console]

Comment: download to local server

Comment: What makes you think that error has anything to do with jQuery? The stack trace is all about `webspeed.js`, whatever that is.

Comment: @Fox I tried and I have the same problem

Comment: @Pointy Because my page contain only jQuery

Comment: If it contains "only jQuery" where's that `webspeed.js` error coming from?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your post; one line is not sufficient.

Comment: @Pointy there si no more code https://i.imgur.com/7iBbP3M.png

Comment: @executable Maybe that code in `webspeed.js` checks if jquery library is loaded (`if(window.jQuery) {}` for example) so when you include jquery is allowing the code to run which throws that exception

Comment: @Alon it seems like jQuery is loaded https://i.imgur.com/2FOJyCU.png

Comment: A web page with nothing but the jQuery script tag will not cause that error.

Comment: @Pointy I have no more code, I will post an issue on their git

Comment: What exactly are you doing with your page? What browser are you using?

Comment: I just want to get rid of that error, I'm using Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (64 bits). I tried with firefox and I have no error

Comment: @executable Oh, it's an extension [check the support tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speedtest-by-ookla/pgjjikdiikihdfpoppgaidccahalehjh) - You'll find that you're not the only one having this issue

Comment: @Alon Thank you, I would never figure it out ! I removed the extension and the error is gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with jQuery or its CDN.

From the error log, you can see that the error originates from `webspeed.js`. Since you precise that you only import the jQuery script, this shows that this error originates from an extension.

The script tries to contact `speedtest.net` and the request gets blocked by CORB, thus throwing an uncaught error. This also gives a hint that the extension is made likely to be offered by `speedtest.net` or a related corporation. As [@alon-eitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan) found, this is indeed the case: the [speedtest extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speedtest-by-ookla/pgjjikdiikihdfpoppgaidccahalehjh) includes such a script that has been known for triggering similar errors.

Pausing the extension or configuring it not to run on your website is likely to fix the error. I'd recommend removing it completely, as network speed analysis and much more can already be natively performed by Chrome thanks to [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/).

Comment: I am getting same error on chrome browser but it is fine when I use firefox. Obviously I am not using Jquery in my project. If it is because of extension in the project than why it is not visible in firefox.

Comment: The extension is a Chrome extension so its behavior is Chrome specific